# Multi level bootstrap menu (in Toranj theme)

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a responsive menu, based on the toranj theme. But I'm stuck at the multi level menu workings.

Site : http://sendtomail.com/ (active development)

I have NO clue on what could be wrong. the behaviour is quit random, and have limited it down to the following:

- on the homepage, the 1st level works and you can click on it to open the next level.
- on any other page, the 2nd level does not open
- you cannot get to the 3rd level, tough I followed the example template

Menu should look like this:

- Onze School

  - Historiek
  - Wie is Wie?

    - Schoolbestuur
    - Ons Team
    - Organogram
  - Visie
  - Dagindeling

code :

```
                    <!-- Navigation --> 
                    <ul id="navigation">
                        <li id="school" class="menu-item menu-item-has-children"><a href="#">Onze School</a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li class="nav-prev"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>Onze School</a></li>
                                <li id="school-historiek" class="menu-item "><a href="http://sendtomail.com/school/historiek">Historiek</a></li>
                                <li id="wie-is-wie" class="menu-item menu-item-has-children"><a href="#">Wie is wie?</a>
                                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                                        <li class="nav-prev"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>Wie is wie?</a></li>
                                        <li id="wie-is-wie-schoolbestuur" class="menu-item"><a href="<a href="http://sendtomail.com/school/wie-is-wie/schoolbestuur">Schoolbestuur</a></li>
                                        <li id="wie-is-wie-team" class="menu-item"><a href="<a href="http://sendtomail.com/school/wie-is-wie/team">Ons Team</a></li>
                                        <li id="wie-is-wie-organogram" class="menu-item"><a href="<a href="http://sendtomail.com/school/wie-is-wie/organogram">Organogram</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li id="school-visie" class="menu-item "><a href="http://sendtomail.com/school/visie">Visie</a></li>
                                <li id="school-dagindeling" class="menu-item "><a href="http://sendtomail.com/school/dagindeling">Dagindeling</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul> 
                    <!-- /Navigation -->
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code, or [create an mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Current code is live @ http://www.sendtomail.com/

Comment: I haven't found a solution. Looks like their is issue in their code you are referencing. If you remove the first "sub-menu" class the 2nd will work.

Comment: A working example is right here : http://demo.owwwlab.com/wp-toranj/#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay you have a different version of the custom.js than the working example and they had a few that you were missing.

Add the following under your Magnific-popup.js

```
<script src="http://demo.owwwlab.com/wp-toranj/wp-content/themes/toranj/assets/js/vendors/jquery.dropdown.js?ver=1.12.3" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://demo.owwwlab.com/wp-toranj/wp-content/themes/toranj/assets/js/vendors/jquery.lazyload.min.js?ver=1.12.3" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Replace your custom.js call with the following

```
<script src="http://demo.owwwlab.com/wp-toranj/wp-content/themes/toranj/assets/js/custom.js?ver=1.12.3" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

After making these changes there is a script error in IE. I'll let you look into that.